# Android NDK. What does #define LOGI(...) mean. And few basic questions

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am new to NDK, but I sucessfully done some basic exaples, but I want to ask some simple questions (вasically, I understand what it means, but I want to be convinced of the correctness). Here is code, can anyone explain what every line means:

```
#ifdef __ANDROID__
#define LOG_TAG "MyNative"
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define LOG_TAG    __FILE__ ":" STRINGIFY(__MyNative__)
#define LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

Thank you very-very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are all C preprocessor directives.

> ```
> #ifdef __ANDROID__
> ...
> #endif
> ```

This part is only processed if the preprocessor symbol `__ANDROID__` is defined.

> ```
> #define LOG_TAG "MyNative"
> ```

This defines a macro `LOG_TAG` that expands to `"MyNative"`.

> ```
> #define STRINGIFY(x) #x
> ```

This defines a macro `STRINGIFY` that takes an argument `x` and turns it to a string literal with the `#`.

> ```
> #define LOG_TAG    __FILE__ ":" STRINGIFY(__MyNative__)
> ```

This defines a macro `LOG_TAG` that expands to three string literals (that get automatically concatenated together). `__FILE__` is a built-in macro that expands to the current source file name, `STRINGIFY(__MyNative__)` produces `"__MyNative__"`.

> ```
> #define LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
> #define LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
> ```

These define two macros that take in a variable number of arguments `(...)`. The macro is expanded so that the `__VA_ARGS__` is replaced with the variable number of arguments as a comma-separated list. `__android_log_print()` is a C varargs function (like `printf()`) that accepts variable number of args.